# How to sample a dataframe based on a given distribution where limited classes attenuate the other classes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a distribution of classes and a dataframe of rows of examples of those classes is there a simple/fast way to sample from the dataframe a distribution matching the given distribution where classes without enough examples attenuate the number of examples in the other classes:

e.g.

```
+------+-------+-------+
| col1 | col2 | class |
+------+-------+-------+
| 4    | 45    | A     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 5    | 66    | B     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 5    | 6     | C     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 4    | 6     | A     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 321  | 1     | A     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 32   | 432   | A     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 5    | 3     | B     |
+------+-------+-------+

given a dataframe like above and the distribution like below:
+-------+--------------+
| class | proportion   |
+-------+--------------+
| A     | 0.50         |
+-------+--------------+
| B     | 0.25         |
+-------+--------------+
| C     | 0.25         |
+-------+--------------+

I would like to return something like:
+------+-------+-------+
| col1 | col2 | class |
+------+-------+-------+
| 5    | 66    | B     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 5    | 6     | C     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 4    | 6     | A     |
+------+-------+-------+
| 32   | 432   | A     |
+------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.sample` supports weighing entities:

```
s = pd.Series({'A': 0.5, 'B': 0.25, 'C': 0.25})
df.sample(n, weights=df['class'].map(s/df['class'].value_counts()))
```

To get more info on the topic, search for "label shift"

Comment: This will always return n amount of rows from the df. I want it to return the maximum amount possible while still confined by the distribution. E.g. imagine there were 10000 rows of class 'A' and only 2 rows of 'B' and 'C' each. Given the same distribution I would like a df with 8 rows (4 'A', 2 'B', 2 'C').